# Is there a simple way to change the "text changed" status in QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtextedit

I need to verify my source file and even omit some "service" lines,
so I do it using `appendPlainText()` of `QPlainTextEdit`. Appending a line
of course means a change,so after loading the file, the asterisk meaning that the file changed appears. I would like to have the more consistent behavior, that after loading, this status signal is not set. How can I reset it, after I loaded the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the part of the code that emits the unwanted signal by two [`QObject::blockSignals`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals) calls:

```
textEdit->blockSignals(true);
// load from file
textEdit->blockSignals(false);
```

or directly on `QTextEdit::document` (will block fewer other signals, I suppose):

```
textEdit->document()->blockSignals(true);
// load from file
textEdit->document()->blockSignals(false);
```

Maybe even call [`QTextEdit::setModified`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit-compat.html#setModified) immediately after loading (two signals will be emitted).

Try each one of these out and give me know if any of them doesn't work.